# What is API URL executed by Twitter4j? (Search API)

Tags: api, url, search, twitter, twitter4j

I use Twitter4J libraries to access Twitter through their Search API. 
I provide such a query to Twitter4j:

```
Query{query='#hungergames', lang='null', locale='null', maxId=-1, rpp=100, page=-1, since='null', sinceId=241378725860618240, geocode='null', until='null', resultType='recent', nextPageQuery='null'}
```

and

```
result = twitter.search(query);
```

but I am not sure what URL is executes internally. 
**Any insights into how I can find that out?**

I know Twitter API documents how I should form the URL to query something [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) but I want to know what URL did Twitter4J execute.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to sniff network traffic with a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

I used the following code to replicate your query:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    Query query = new Query("#hungergames");
    query.rpp(100);
    query.setSinceId(241378725860618240L);
    query.setResultType(Query.RECENT);
    System.out.println(query);
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
        System.out.println(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
    }
}
```

The line that prints the query gives me:

> Query{query='#hungergames', lang='null', locale='null', maxId=-1, rpp=100, page=-1, since='null', sinceId=241378725860618240, geocode='null', until='null', resultType='recent'}

By sniffing the network traffic I found that the code is requesting the following URL:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hungergames&rpp=100&since_id=241378725860618240&result_type=recent&with_twitter_user_id=true&include_entities=true